# Deleting files using CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, file-handling, delete-file

I'm not sure if this is the proper function to delete a single file (say an image) using [CodeIgniter](http://codeigniter.com).

```
$this->load->helper('file');    
delete_files('path')
```

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/file_helper.html

However it lists that this function is to delete entire directories, and makes no mention of how it handles individual files (if a path to only 1 file is given).  Before I start testing with it, I figured I would check if anyone has ran into this problem before?

I simply want to use a CodeIgniter function to delete individually uploaded images (say user profile images) but I am unable to find anything in the documentation / user guide that helps me achieve this (yes I know I need to have proper permissions first and all that, but that is out of scope of this question).

**regarding unlink()**

what I was hoping for is a built in CI function that would alert me to something stupid like "no delete permission" or other factors like "file is in use". I found unlink() to sometimes not work (without throwing me an error). Hence why I asked...

Comment: What's wrong with using `unlink()` in PHP?

Comment: Agree with @Russell, no need to go for codeigniter function; just use unlink(<file path>);

Comment: @Russell Dias: `unlink` cannot delete recursively, at least.

Comment: You can check if it `is_writable` first. Most people on this site frown upon error suppression `@`. However, you could suppress the `E_WARNING` that is caused by `unlink()`, *but still handle the error on failure*, through what ever means you use to organize your errors.

Comment: @zerkms: I was under the impression that he wanted to delete *individual* files. Unless I am mistaken here.

Comment: @Russell Dias: yep, i just mentioned that there are possible scenarios to not use `unlink`, but CI's `delete_files`.

Comment: @Russell Dias - If you want to post your initial `unlink()` as an answer please do. I've done some research since posting this, and it doesn't look like CodeIgniter has anything other than the PHP default unlink to use in this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I posted in the comments, you could utilize PHP's `unlink()` function. However, this seems to return an `E_WARNING` error upon returning false. Like I also stated in the comments, you could utilize error suppression, *but* still handle the error in an appropriate manner, should it fail to delete a file.

Comment: Thanks Russ! Correct and simplest answer to it all ;)